# How do not mix Callable method call in android?

Tags: android

In android when i use proGuard to mix the jar, why implements Callable cannot like Runnable, also mixed!
how do i resolve this question? My Callable was implemented in inner class! below is the mixed code!

```
class a implements Callable<HttpResponse>  {
private HttpPost xG;

public a(HttpPost paramHttpPost)
{
  this.xG = paramHttpPost;
}

public HttpResponse hz()
  throws Exception
{
  HttpResponse localHttpResponse = null;
  try
  {
    HttpClient localHttpClient = j.iC();
    localHttpResponse = localHttpClient.execute(this.xG);
  }
  catch (Exception localException)
  {
    b.u(ErrorUtils.getErrorInfoFromException(localException));
  }
  return localHttpResponse;
}
```

}

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you paste some sample code to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The interface `Callable` doesn't get obfuscated because it's part of the standard Android API. Classes, enums and interfaces defined by the Android platform are outside of the scope of what ProGuard can obfuscate.

In your code, you can see that other things like `Exception` and `HttpClient` didn't get "mixed" either.

Comment: i know but the hz(), what happened? it'll throw abstract class not implement Callable call()!

Comment: Make sure you add an @Override tag to that method. Otherwise, you can add configuration to ProGuard to ignore that class: `-keep class ** implements Callable { *; }`

Comment: yes, i add it, but also mixed! some of the situation not throw the exception !